# Problems downloading file in bucket directory from Google Storage

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am able to download an object from my bucket

```
var bucket_name = "digital-jorgesys-454.appspot.com";            
var object_name = "earnings_202107_212121-10.zip";
```

but now I am trying to download a file inside a directory

```
var bucket_name = "digital-jorgesys-454.appspot.com";            
var object_name = "/earnings/earnings_202107_212121-10.zip";
```

[image]

I get only the message:

> Exception thrown: 'Google.GoogleApiException' in mscorlib.dll

I have the required permissions, this is my Code:

```
private async Task DownloadFromBucket()
{
    //To get Service Account keys go to : https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts          
    var GCSServiceAccountEmail = "google-financial-reports@digital-jorgesys-454.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
    var P12KeyFullPath = @"C:\Data\jorgesys\GoogleFinancialReport\digital-jorgesys-454-f4e36f8fabcde.p12";           
    var P12KeySecret = "itsmysecret";
    Console.WriteLine($"*** \" async Task DownloadFromBucket()()\" ....");
                        
    var bucket_name = "digital-jorgesys-454.appspot.com";            
    var object_name = "earnings/earnings_202107_2138916436889858-70.zip";            

    try
    {
        _ = DownloadFile(GCSServiceAccountEmail, P12KeyFullPath, P12KeySecret, bucket_name, object_name);               
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DownloadFile ERROR: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

}


private async Task DownloadFile(string GCSServiceAccountEmail, string P12KeyFullPath, string P12KeySecret, string GCSBucketName, string filePathInGcs)
{
    try { 
    const string LocalDownloadPath = @"C:\Data\jorgesys\GoogleFinancialReport\";
    const string GCSApplicationName = "Jorgesys";
    var certificate
             = new X509Certificate2(P12KeyFullPath, P12KeySecret,
                   X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
                   X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |
                   X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
        new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(GCSServiceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = new[] { StorageService.Scope.DevstorageReadWrite }
        }.FromCertificate(certificate));

    var service = new StorageService(
        new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            ApplicationName = GCSApplicationName,
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        }
        );

    var fileRequest = new ObjectsResource.GetRequest(service, GCSBucketName, filePathInGcs);
      var fileMetaDataObj = fileRequest.Execute();
    fileRequest.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += DownloadProgress;
    fileRequest.MediaDownloader.ChunkSize = (256 * 1024);       
    var downloadStream =
             new FileStream(Path.Combine(LocalDownloadPath, filePathInGcs), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    await fileRequest.MediaDownloader.DownloadAsync(fileMetaDataObj.MediaLink, downloadStream, CancellationToken.None);

    service.Dispose();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DownloadFile() Error: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: probably is a nonsense, but, can you try removing the first slash character from your object name? I mean: `var object_name = "earnings/earnings_202107_212121-10.zip";`. Please, be aware that from the point of view of GCS there is no such a concept of directory, only object names that can contain slashes. Some tools treat that slashes as "directories", but actually they are not

Comment: Thank you @jccampanero, is not nonsense, I see that this path is created "digital-jorgesys-454.appspot.com//earnings/earnings_202107_212121-10.zip" and is invalid, but I have found more troubles before this...

Comment: What problems mate? I only have a few minutes now, but can I help?

Answer (score 1):

Well, trying to get more info about this issue I found the problem, first this is one error:

> No such object:
> digital-jorgesys-454.appspot.com//earnings/earnings_202107_2138916436889858-70.zip
> [404] Errors [    Message[No such object:
> digital-jorgesys-454.appspot.com//earnings/earnings_202107_212121-10.zip]
> Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global] ]

The object was not found because a separator "/" was added automatically, so I made this change:

```
  var bucket_name = "digital-jorgesys-454.appspot.com";            
  //var object_name = "/earnings/earnings_202107_212121-10.zip";     
  var object_name = "earnings/earnings_202107_212121-10.zip";
```

And now the path to access the object is correct:

```
digital-jorgesys-454.appspot.com/earnings/earnings_202107_212121-10.zip
```

Then, to download the file the path is incorrect (

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' in
> mscorlib.dll

) because I need a similar structure to download the file inside the same directory, so we must be sure that the download path must really contain the `\earnings\` directory.

```
const string LocalDownloadPath = @"C:\Data\jorgesys\GoogleFinancialReport\";
```